# Why Would A Queen Strider Connect With Shadow Dancers?

Tags: society, magic

Background: The Queen Strider is like a Queen Bee or Ant, except for the following differences:

1. She's huge and resembles a Spinosaurus, with chitinous hide, segmented eyes, antennae *and* horns, a stinger-tipped tail, and so forth. If you're thinking mutant dragon, you're not wrong.....
2. She's a living shadow-conventional weaponry and non-divine spells pass straight through her. Essentially, she can touch *you*, but you can't touch *her.*
3. She has four draconic wings and is capable of flight
4. She telepathically controls her entire colony
5. She can fire blasts of extremely toxic black smoke or solid shadows

While working on the logistics of feeding her children (see ([Feeding Shadow Striders](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192988/feeding-shadow-striders)), the Queen Strider formed a cult to help. Later, when she replaced one of the cult's Dancer's gaudy outfit with something she made herself out of her shadow-silk, she accidentally discovered a Class Variant: **Shadow Dancer.**

Shadow Dancers can be telepathically controlled, harness and manipulate shadows, and are completely, wholly devoted to the colony (like a sentient ant would be?). However, the Queen Strider doesn't want to gain Shadow Dancers as slaves that coincidentally happen to be her species favorite food alone; she actually forms and seeks emotional connections with them. In essence, she cares for the Dancers she takes and enchants in her own twisted way. Kill a Soldier Strider and she'll be angry; kill a Shadow Dancer, and she'll be just as angry, maybe even more so.

So my question is: **Why would a monster queen seek and form emotional connections with human beings?**

Additional Information:

1. Dancers are people who hold the Dancer Class, and only 5% of them are male. Chances are they're female, just like the Queen Strider.
2. She is not keeping the Shadow Dancers as food; they may be human, but the Striders can't eat them (the Queen won't let them).
3. The Queen genuinely enjoys the presence of the Shadow Dancers and values them for their unique selves. She may be annoyed or angry with them from time to time, or think them strange, but she appreciates their idiosyncrasies, sort of like how people can love their siblings despite how annoying/infuriating they are.
4. The Shadow Dancers are elite in the colony; Soldiers may guard the Queen, but the Dancers bring her food/feed her, keep her company, cast spells for her, act as couriers for the Queen, and so forth. Basically, they are her handmaidens.

If you need more details, let me know, I'll add it ASAP.

Comment: These are a DandD race, not a race from traditional fantasy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Companionship**

Her minions are made to have little will of their own, they do as she wishes as instinct. Humans have their own minds - perhaps lower but they at least have the ability to communicate ideas that may be novel to the queen. Maybe a different perspective could help a queen from becoming too narrow-minded. Other queens have died out because they lacked any views but the echoes of their own thoughts bounced back at them from the striders that lack their own minds.

The Queen's favourite prey is human and humans are well known for their pesky habit of wanting to fight back against the things that want to eat them. Queens with a narrow-minded view and no insight to human ingenuity have fallen to these pests. Connection to the Shadow Dancers afford a Queen insight to the minds of her enemy and a method of infiltration.

Comment: Ah, very insightful! Thank you!

Comment: Striders have minds of their own, but not much of one-they're more like robots or insects than anything else. So, your answer is very valid despite that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you seek and form an emotional attachment to a cat? It’s a different (ostensibly lower) lifeform, yet you shelter it it, love it, and even (if it isn’t a working cat) feed it.

Basically: *she thinks we’re cute*.

Not in a romantic way, more of a ‘Aww look, Joe Bloggs is slaughtering the Enemies of the Hive again! Who’s a good wittle Homo sapiens den!’ kind of way. We’re fuzzy, we’re funny, we’re highly adaptable, we form bonds in the most unlikely of places.

Frankly: humans are ideal pets for Unknowable Terrors Of The Night.

Comment: Insightful and funny! So, you're saying humans would be ideal pets for Chthulhu himself?

Comment: @Alendyias: Chthulhu would probably prefer octopi/oids/uses, but pretty much: yeah. A mix of cuteness, intelligence and lethal utility makes cats, dogs and even otters very useful pets/companions for us. Cant think of a reason that wouldn’t be true for humans and other beings.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just surprised someone thought eldritch horrors would want humans as pets.

Comment: @Alendyias: Humans keep shrimp, snakes, fish, octopuses, spiders and worms as pets. Just imagine how alien and eldritch we must seem to them!

Comment: I never thought of it that way; wow, new perspective.